Custom Error Message on ContentDistribution Object in Apex Trigger
I am trying to create a apex trigger on contentdistribution object by following this documentation and added a logic to throw a custom error message as 'This file is not allowed to be delivered.' but when I try to share the file by hitting Public Link, I am getting 'Can't create public link. You can try asking the file owner for access.' which is a standard error message. Why I can't see my custom error message triggered from apex trigger? Am I missing something?
Thanks In Advance!!

Does the debug log show that the trigger is invoked for the share operation?
